# Create a square grid in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a 5 x 5 grid which will be overlayed on a map, I have starting latitude and longitude coordinates, which could be the top right hand corner of the grid for example (doesn't really matter). each point would be an equal (say -10) amount different to the previous coordinates.

I'm having trouble coding it:

```
latcoords  <- c(origincoords$results$geometry$location$lat)
lngcoords  <- c(origincoords$results$geometry$location$lng)

griddf <- data.frame(latcoords, lngcoords)
names(griddf)[1]<-paste("latcoords")
names(griddf)[2]<-paste("lngcoords")
x <- 1 
y <- 1
while(x < 5){
while(5  < 5) {
    griddf <- rbind(griddf$latcoords[x] -10, griddf$lngcoords[x])

    }
griddf <- rbind(griddf$latcoords[x], griddf$lngcoords[x] - 10)
x <- x + 1
y <- 1
}
```

Where am I going wrong here...

Comment: What should your outcome look like?  Can you write it out without trying to code it?

Comment: How are you plotting your map? If you're using ggplot2 and ggmap, just use the scale functions to set gridlines where you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `seq` and `expand.grid` functions.  `seq` creates a sequence of numbers ("each point would be an equal (say -10) amount different to the previous coordinates") and `expand.grid` creates a dataframe from all combinations of the supplied vectors ("create a 5 x 5 grid"):

```
start_lat <- 100
start_lng <- 0
griddf <- expand.grid(latcoords = seq(from = start_lat, by = -10, l = 5),
                      lngcoords = seq(from = start_lng, by = -10, l = 5))
griddf
#    latcoords lngcoords
# 1        100         0
# 2         90         0
# 3         80         0
# 4         70         0
# 5         60         0
# 6        100       -10
# 7         90       -10
# 8         80       -10
# 9         70       -10
# 10        60       -10
# 11       100       -20
# 12        90       -20
# 13        80       -20
# 14        70       -20
# 15        60       -20
# 16       100       -30
# 17        90       -30
# 18        80       -30
# 19        70       -30
# 20        60       -30
# 21       100       -40
# 22        90       -40
# 23        80       -40
# 24        70       -40
# 25        60       -40
```

(Edited to set vector names inside call to `expand.grid`, as pointed out by @alistaire.)

Comment: You can set names inside `expand.grid` just like `data.frame`, e.g. `expand.grid(lat = seq(from = 0, by = -10, l = 5),
            lng = seq(from = 100, by = -10, l = 5))`